# PHP database DATE compare to todays DATE

Tags: php, sql

In the database, I Have DOB table wich is DATE .  so I have problem in search function, because I want to search people by Date to be correct age at any time.  So  fields in search is AGE for example 18-25  ,  . I want to make `searchage1` = 18 in this example and `searchage2` = 25.

```
 `dob BETWEEN ".$search_data['searchage1']." AND ".$search_data['searchage2'];`
```

I want to convert this 18  and 25 into DATE then Compare it to Database DATES . I have tried some possiblity with no sucess, any idea?

Comment: Yes  its DATE yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: what DB is this? if it's mysql, then only yyyy-mm-dd is a valid date/time format. `yyyy/mm/dd` will be treated as a string, NOT a date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22504155/432232 check this answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to calculate the `age` based form the `dob` field, then use this in your `WHERE` statements.

Please see these threads on how to calculate age in SQL: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5773632/128161) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql)

EG:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dob, '2016-06-28')/365.25 AS `age` WHERE `age` >= '18' AND `age` =< '25';
```

or

```
SELECT *, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)) AS `age` WHERE `age` >= '18' AND `age` =< '25';
```

Comment: (dob, '2016-06-28')
What 2016-06-28 means? can I use (dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) instead of it ?

Comment: That calculates the difference between the two dates, the latter being today's date. I just took that SQL from the other answers I've posted.

Comment: So if we looking for difference  then as it seems 2016-06-28 is TODAYS date so can we just use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` AKA `NOW` returns the time too, so that may throw your calculations off a bit.

Comment: Hey Jamie, can you please help me more clear I appreciate that.
My sql connect: '
$this->db->query('(SELECT CAT.heading,MODEL.autoid,MODEL.aname,MODEL.outcall1,MODEL.gender,MODEL.online,MODEL.age,MODEL.thumbimg,username=0 FROM regio_model AS MODEL LEFT JOIN regio_categories AS CAT ON CAT.autoid=MODEL.outcall2 WHERE'.$wh.')'
wh means whatever I Do for that date calculatin,  I cannot change this strcuture since so much thing builded like that in file.  so at this time  : 
$wh = "DATEDIFF(dob, '2016-06-28')/365.25  AS `age` WHERE `age` >= '18' AND `age` =< '25';";
This actually taking error

Comment: I cannot see exactly what error is cuz of Codeingiter, but  I am sure the error is cuz of $wh is wrong .

Comment: The `age` calculate needs to be in the first part of the SQL, if you see my examples.

Comment: I am trying but does not works, can u add ur following code into my Sql that I sent you AND PASTE IT HERE?