# Group by age ranges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a date of birth field(type date) and user_id in the table and we want to get count of users group by age based on the date of birth field

For e.g. after running we get following records

```
Age  Total_Users 
1-20    50
20-30   100
30-50   500
50-100  600
```

how we to write this type of query? Please suggest. Currently I am
managing via php code but it is taking too much time due to lots of records
Thanks

Comment: How do your raw data look like? please post some sample data

Comment: Look at the correct, not the accepted, answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql . Then use GROUP BY on the computed ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a query like below would do the job.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 20 THEN '1-20'
     WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 30 THEN '20-30'
     WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 50 THEN '30-50'
     WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 50 THEN '50-100' END AS age,
COUNT(*) total
FROM dob_table
GROUP BY age;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f683b/3/0)</kbd>

**Input:**

```
| id |                 birth_date |
|----|----------------------------|
|  1 | February, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|  2 | February, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|  3 | February, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|  4 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00 |
|  5 | February, 27 1989 00:00:00 |
|  6 | February, 27 1989 00:00:00 |
|  7 | February, 27 1989 00:00:00 |
|  8 | February, 27 1989 00:00:00 |
|  9 | February, 27 1989 00:00:00 |
```

**Output:**

```
age      total
1-20        4
20-30       5
```

Comment: Hii , Your Query worked for me but there is only problem that it is not working with limit if we pass limit like 0,10 or etc..

Comment: On what the `Limit 0,10` you want to apply on?

Answer (score 0):

there's a simpler way:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 20 THEN '0-20'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 30 THEN '20-30'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 40 THEN '30-40'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 50 THEN '30-40'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 60 THEN '40-50'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 70 THEN '50-60'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 80 THEN '60-70'
    WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())) <= 110 THEN '70+' END AS age,
COUNT(*) total
FROM duo
GROUP BY age;
```