# SQL age check to current date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I'm just trying to select the persons that are not yet 30.
Table:

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| fname  | lname |    dob     |
+--------+-------+------------+
| Steven | Carl  | 1964-07-07 |
| John   | Handy | 1980-06-03 |
| Mary   | Jane  | 2000-11-12 |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

I've tried doing something like that, I know that checks for today's date and it is wrong.

`CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)`

Maybe I can subtract the year with 30 and check for that date or something like that?

```
SELECT  fname, lname,  FROM Persons
WHERE dob >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an age from a D.O.B field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date arithmetic:

```
select * from persons where dob + interval 30 year > curdate()
```