# How to get age by subtracting current year from date of birth in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql `5.7.18-log`.

I have a query as follows, which result name and date of birth in output.

`select uid,Name, Dob from table1;`

Data:

```
uid       Name          Dob
K-1       Alex          1996-01-01 05:30:00
K-2       Mike          1983-05-26 05:30:00
K-3       Jim           1992-12-29 05:30:00
```

I want to extract age using the year and month of `Dob` column and extracting it from the current year and month.

Required output:

```
uid       Name          Dob                    Age
K-1       Alex          1996-01-01 05:30:00    25
K-2       Mike          1983-05-26 05:30:00    37
K-3       Jim           1992-12-29 05:30:00    28
```

Comment: [How to get an age from a D.O.B field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Using year and month only?

Comment: Do you really need time of birth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is your friend](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT t.`uid`, t.`Name`, t.`Dob`,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.`Dob`, CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM `table1` t
```

This will always return a whole number *rounded down* to the nearest integer.